# Unable to send emails with published netcore2.1 app

Tags: c#, email, .net-core

I have inconsistent behavior with sending emails when running the built `Release` version of my project through VS 2017 versus the `publish` version. The project is published with the below code:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win-x64 --framework netcoreapp2.1
```

When I use the published files (`Source\<project>\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64\publish`) as a source for a Windows service, the email sending functionality does not work and no errors are thrown/logged. Through logging I can confirm that the correct lines are hit.

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = configSettings.SmtpClientConfig.Host,
    Port = configSettings.SmtpClientConfig.Port,
    UseDefaultCredentials = configSettings.SmtpClientConfig.UseDefaultCredentials,
    DeliveryMethod = configSettings.SmtpClientConfig.DeliveryMethod,
    PickupDirectoryLocation = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + configSettings.SmtpClientConfig.PickupDirectoryLocation,
};

smtpClient.Send(await mail);
```

On the other hand, when I run the `Release` version of the exact same project through VS 2017, it sends out the emails no problem.

I have run the Windows service and Visual Studio under the same account so the issues shouldn't be permissions.

What could be the cause of the published version of my project not being able to send out the emails?

Comment: Sounds to me like you have an async/await block.  can you post the code where `mail` is defined?

Comment: Looks like the async was fine. Had a null config for the `DeliveryMethod` which caused the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had a missing config for the `DeliveryMethod` which prevented the sending of the mails. Adding a `DeliveryMethod` of `0` fixed the issue. Don't know why this didn't throw an exception though